# how to create svg animations without using js or css

Tags: animation, svg, jquery-animate, adobe, open-source

How a designer who does not know how to code may create svg animations? Tried using Adobe Animate CC with Animate SVG Exporter but when the .fla file is exported to svg, it looses all or most of the animations.

Comment: You can use [SMIL](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) animations or CSS animations. However you must know that this is not a proper question. Please read more about [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

### SVG smil animation

Suppose you have this `svg`

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;stroke:#FEC558;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256;}
    .st1{fill:#FFC656;}
</style>
<path class="st0"   d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z"/>
    <g>
        <polygon class="st1"
    points="14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7 
                32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2   "/>
        <polygon class="st1"
      points="19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5       15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

- Determine the length of objects using JS

  `<script>
           function TotalLength(){
            var path = document.querySelector('#circle');
          var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
          alert("path length - " + len);
          };
    </script>`

  **Path length:**

  for circle - `138px`

  for trapezium - `60px`

  for triangle - `35px`

  - Command for drawing animation of objects

`<animate id="an_circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="138;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />`

`<animate id="an_trap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="60;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />`

`<animate id="an_triangle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_trap.end" values="35;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />`

- The animation of drawing a triangle will begin when the animation of
  drawing of a trapezoid

  `begin="an_trap.end"`
- Animation fill color trapezium will begin when the animation is
  finished drawing a circle

  `<animate id="fill_trap" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="an_circle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />`
- An animation of the color filling of the triangle will begin when the
  fill animation of the trapezium ends

  `<animate id="fill_triangle" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="fill_trap.end-0.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />`

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;stroke:#FEC558;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256;}
    .st1{fill:#FFC656;}
</style>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
         
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#33363D"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5B5D5A"/>
</lineargradient>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>

<path id="circle" class="st0" stroke-dashoffset="138" stroke-dasharray="138" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z">
<animate id="an_circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="138;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</path>
    <g stroke-width="0.5">
       <path id="trap" class="st1" stroke-dashoffset="60" stroke-dasharray="60" style="fill:none; stroke:#FEC558;" d="M14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7  32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2z">
        <animate id="an_trap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="60;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate id="fill_trap" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="an_circle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
        <path id="triangle" class="st1" stroke-dashoffset="35" stroke-dasharray="35" style="fill:none; stroke:#FEC558;"  d="M19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7">
  
  <animate id="an_triangle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_trap.end" values="35;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate id="fill_triangle" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="fill_trap.end-0.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

### CSS solution

- An animation for drawing shape outlines is implemented using CSS
  rules:

*for the circle*

```
.circle {
    fill:none;
    stroke:#FEC558;
    stroke-dashoffset:138.5;
    stroke-dasharray:138.5;
    animation: circle_stroke 2s ease-in forwards;
        } 

    @keyframes circle_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 138.5;
    }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

- Animating the trapezium contour drawing and filling it with color

code below

```
.trap {
    stroke-dashoffset:60;
    stroke-dasharray:60;
        animation:trap_stroke 2s ease-in-out forwards,  trap_fill  ease-in 3s forwards;

    }

    @keyframes trap_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60.5;
    }

      100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }  

    @keyframes trap_fill {
    0% {
    fill: none;
    }

      100% {
    fill: #FEC558;
      }
    }
```

*Full animation code*

```css
 .trap, .triangle {
   stroke:#FEC558;
   stroke-width:0.5;
 fill:none;
   }
 
 .circle {
 fill:none;
 stroke:#FEC558;
 stroke-dashoffset:138.5;
 stroke-dasharray:138.5;
 animation: circle_stroke 2s ease-in forwards;
  } 
 
 @keyframes circle_stroke {
 0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 138.5;
 }
 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }
 

 
 
 .trap {
 stroke-dashoffset:60;
 stroke-dasharray:60;
  animation:trap_stroke 2s ease-in-out forwards,  trap_fill  ease-in 3s forwards;
 
 }
 
 @keyframes trap_stroke {
 0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60.5;
 }
    
   100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }  
 
 @keyframes trap_fill {
 0% {
    fill: none;
 }
    
   100% {
    fill: #FEC558;
   }
 }  


 .triangle {
 stroke-dashoffset:35.5;
 stroke-dasharray:35.5;
 
 animation: triangle_stroke 1s ease-in-out forwards, triangle_fill 3.5s ease-in forwards;
 }  
 
 @keyframes triangle_stroke {
 0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35.5;
 }
 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }  
 
 @keyframes triangle_fill {
 0% {
    fill: none;
 }
 100% {
    fill: #FEC558;;
   }
 }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">  

<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
         
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#33363D"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5B5D5A"/>
</lineargradient>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>

<path class="circle" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z"/>

    
       <path class="trap"    d="M14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7  32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2z" />
          
        <path class="triangle"   d="M19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7"/>
 

</svg>
```

**UPD**

Works in all modern browsers, except IE

"[IE10 and IE11 do not support CSS keyframe blocks inside media queries](https://caniuse.com/#search=animation)."

(see the "Known Issues")

Comment: This is lots of code.  I am looking for visual way of creating svg animations.

Comment: @user2306700 To get the answer you need, it was necessary to provide more specific information. Add your attempts. Sorry, I could not help you.

Comment: @user2306700 you've come to the wrong place then I'm afraid. This site is for [programming Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @user2306700, in the second example (second snippet from the top of this answer) you have the answer full explaned before. If you think that you can calculate path length only with your eyes, then you are very wrong. All calculations with the values for animations must be calculated with some code. But you do not see this code in the end examples and because of this you think that all animations were made only using human eyes without calculations but this is wrong. You have here very good answer with very good explanation and you have to mark it as accepted on the left side from the answer.