# SVG vector image animation

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, vector-graphics

I have 3 vector images created in `Adobe Illustrator`.

I want animate this vector quality images same way as `gif` does, fast endless loop sequence of 3 images in `.svg` format in browser `mypage.php` `<img src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="" alt="" width="65" height="45"/>`.

What would be most correct way to get such animation for `.svg`, do I have to use all given methods to create vector animation, or in my scenario case I can do it some different way

Comment: Animate the opacity of the images.

Comment: @Robert Longson Hello! I have 3 vector files and `Adobe Illustrator` project files, but It is first time I have deal with `Scalable Vector Graphics`. Can you provide some close example link for such case please, I guess it must be done with `css`, right?

Comment: @Robert Longson I'm displaying single `.svg` just this way `<img src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="" alt="" width="65" height="45"/>` as any other format

Comment: @Robert Longson Yes, in browser, it is `html`, `js`, `php` page `mypage.php`

Comment: Did you search about this issue into Stackoverflow ? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511615/how-to-create-svg-animations-without-using-js-or-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do it.  Given the information you have provided, here is one way.

We stack the frames on top of one another. Then make them visible one at a time.

```css
.sequence {
  position: relative;
}

.sequence img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;  /* start all frames invisible */
  animation: cycle 3s steps(1) infinite;
}

/* three images, so each gets made visible for 1/3 of the time */
@keyframes cycle {
  0%  { opacity: 1; }
  33% { opacity: 0; }
}

/* start (ie. show) the second frame 1 sec after the first */
.sequence img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

/* start (ie. show) the third frame 2 sec after the first */
.sequence img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="sequence">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/animals"/>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature"/>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/people"/>
</div>
```

These images happen to be JPEGs, but it doesn't matter what type they are. Your SVGs should work.

Given you have SVGs, you might find it better to combine them in a single SVG. Put the contents for each frame in it's own group (`<g>` element). Then use a similar approach as above, but instead show the groups one at a time.

Comment: Hello, I need single animated image for page, so  it seems this method fully answers to my question, I have just  use 0.1 and 0.2 with cycle 0.3s instead second to make it fast

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, the fact that it are svg images is not relevant.

You can create an element and animate trough the different files as background.

```css
div{
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  animation:  rotateImages 1s infinite; 
}

@keyframes rotateImages {
  0%   { background: url("https://www.placecage.com/g/100/100"); }
  32%   { background: url("https://www.placecage.com/g/100/100"); }
  33%  { background: url("https://www.placecage.com/100/100"); }
  65%  { background: url("https://www.placecage.com/100/100"); }
  66% { background: url("https://www.placecage.com/c/100/100"); }
  100% { background: url("https://www.placecage.com/c/100/100"); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```